# uncaught typeerror undefined is not a function while opening Dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery

while executing this code first time it works but in second time it gives me error to #backinstockpopup

This is my jquery code

```
 $("#backinstockpopup").dialog({
                    resizable: false,
                    title: "Back In stock popup",
                    width: 450,
                    modal: true,
                    position: [450, 200],
                    dialogClass: 'ui-widget-contentrewardpoint',
                     close:function(event,ui)
                        {
                        $("#backinstockpopup").empty();
                        },
                    open: function (event, ui) {
                        jQuery('.ui-widget-header').removeClass("ui-widget-header").addClass("ui-widget-headernew").removeClass("ui-corner-all").addClass("ui-corner-top");

                    }

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

What kind of error you get? Open chrome developer console and have a look.
The first thing i would change is, you can remove and add multiply class at same.

```
$(".element").removeClass("class1 class2");
$(".element").addClass("class3 class4");
```